# Pretty links for PHP pages above WP /blog directory?

Tags: permalinks, links

I've made a new WP installation in a subfolder /blog, set up with "Post name" permalinks.

I'm ready to make several other non-WP website PHP pages which would reside above the /blog directory.

I was wondering - is there a way (1) to make these non-blog pages above the /blog directory have "pretty" (aka "search engine friendly") links (like the /blog pages would have), and (2) if that *is* possible, is there also a way in WP to somehow disallow using the 'above the blog page' names for WP pages or posts, so that they won't conflict?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Admin Dashboard.
2. Click on the Settings menu (or icon).
3. Go to the *General* sub menu.
4. The *WordPress Address (URL)* should match the *Site Address (URL)*
5. Remove `/blog` form the *Site Address (URL)*
6. Click the Save Changes button.

Read [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) for more details.

Comment: I've done that process before but in this instance I don't want to have my blog exist in the site root.  That's why it's in a subfolder.  The root is for my own PHP pages.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think the [Using a pre-existing subdirectory install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) section of that same link will do that of you.

Comment: Thank you, but that would load WP in place of the index.php I already have in root.  Really I just wanted to keep my root index.php, and a few other pages I have in root, to have pretty links as well, without loading WP in root.  I guess an extra .htaccess directive for those particular pages would be in order, though I've yet to find how to write it.